# Quartz Scheduler with EJB as a input

Tags: java, ejb, quartz-scheduler

I am new with the Quartz Scheduler. What I'm trying to do is to invoke the EJB in the default constructor of the Job class but it is throwing an instance error and when I try to remove the EJB as the parameter in the default constructor the deployment fails. Can some one suggest me a solution to use the Quartz Scheduler with the EJB as a parameter to the default constructor in the Job class.

Comment: yes I am aware about it but this is how my lead wants me to design it @BalusC

Comment: Could you please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?